# Enabling TWebBrowser High DPI support

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I am using RAD Studio Rio which has support for High DPI.

But it doesn't seem to work on `TWebBrowser`, at least not by default like it does on other VCL components.

So when I drag the app from Low-DPI to High-DPI monitor, the user interface and all components resize (including the web browser container), but not the content inside web browser which stays the same.

I am sure it can be enabled, because moving Internet Explorer between monitors does change the content size automatically.

So the question is how to enable it for `TWebBrowser` too?

I noticed that when dragging IE window the "Zoom" setting changes automatically (from 100% to 200% - 200% is the DPI scaling value of the High DPI monitor) so it may be done through the use of zoom, or somehow else. But there is also a question of scroll-bar sizes too.

I also noted the existance of `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE` flag which might be useful but I don't know how to utilize it yet.

**EDIT: I've created a `IDocHostUIHandler` descendant class which contains `GetHostInfo` function where I can control the flags, among others add `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE` which automatically zooms TWebBrowser to the system DPI (if system DPI is set to 150%, web browser will automatically also zoom to 150%). There is no need to use `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` registry key for this.**

More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753260(v=vs.85)

Comment: You could try [changing the WebBrowser control's compatibility mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two ways how to do this:

**Solution 1**
Enable IE's `FEATURE_96DPI_PIXEL` for your application via Registry key and value:

```pascal
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Win.Registry,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Winapi.Windows;

procedure EnableDpiAwareness;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  App: string;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    App := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;

    if Reg.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_96DPI_PIXEL', True) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteInteger(App, 1);
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally;
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Solution 2**
Implement a descendant class of `TWebBrowser` that reimplements the `IDocHostUIHandler` interface (like mentioned in the edit of OP):

```pascal
unit DpiAwareWebBrowser;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Mshtmhst,
  SHDocVw;

type
  TDpiAwareWebBrowser = class(TWebBrowser, IDocHostUIHandler)
    strict private
      // IDocHostUIHandler "override"
      function GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

implementation

const
  DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE = $40000000;

function TDpiAwareWebBrowser.GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HRESULT;
begin
  // original code from TWebBrowser.GetHostInfo
  pInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(pInfo);
  pInfo.dwFlags := 0;
  pInfo.dwFlags := pInfo.dwFlags or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER;
  pInfo.dwFlags := pInfo.dwFlags or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME;
  pInfo.dwFlags := pInfo.dwFlags or DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE; // NEW added flag
  Result := S_OK;
//  ResizeScrollBars; // will be called by subsequent routines anyway.
end;

end.
```

Both ways do the same thing.

> **DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE**
> Internet Explorer 8. Causes layout engine to calculate document pixels as 96 dpi. Normally, a document pixel is the same size as a screen pixel. This flag is equivalent to setting the `FEATURE_96DPI_PIXEL` feature control key on a per-host basis.

Source: [Microsoft Docs - DOCHOSTUIFLAG enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753277(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 1):

TWebBrowser wraps InternetExplorer, so the rendering of the control is not done by any of the VCL code, but rather by the embedded Internet Explorer Code. We have used this in various projects and setting the compatability mode is key to getting the display you want.

As IE *can* scale correctly you need to ensure you are operating in the correct mode. @Ondrej Kelle's comment is [a useful article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/patricka/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility) that should show you how to do this so I won't repeat it here.